# Java JNA cant find namedpipe functions in Kernel32

Tags: java, jna, kernel32

So I have this "Beep" function works , but when I try any of namedpipe function it returns :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error
>   looking up function 'WaitNamedPipe': The specified procedure could not
>   be found.

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;



/**
 * @author  
 *
 */
public class NamedPipeNativeFunctions {

    /*
     * Public Declare Function CallNamedPipe Lib "kernel32" Alias
     * "CallNamedPipeA" (ByVal lpNamedPipeName As String, lpInBuffer As Any,
     * ByVal nInBufferSize As Long, lpOutBuffer As Any, ByVal nOutBufferSize As
     * Long, lpBytesRead As Long, ByVal nTimeOut As Long) As Long
     * 
     */
    public interface Kernel32 extends Library {
public long CallNamedPipe (String lpNamedPipeName,long  lpInBuffer ,long nInBufferSize, Pointer  lpOutBuffer,long nOutBufferSize, Pointer lpBytesRead, long  nTimeOut);
public boolean WaitNamedPipe(String lpNamedPipeName,
        int nTimeOut);
public boolean Beep(int FREQUENCY, int DURATION);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myClass myclass = new myClass () ; 
        myClass myclass2 = new myClass () ; 

        Pointer lpOutBuffer =  myclass.getPointer() ; 
        Pointer lpBytesRead  =myclass2.getPointer()  ; 

        Kernel32 lib = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class);
        //lib.CallNamedPipe("1234TestPipe", 255, 255, lpOutBuffer , 255, lpBytesRead , 5000); 
        lib.Beep(698, 500); // works 
         boolean sucess =   lib.WaitNamedPipe("hgf" ,(int) 5000 ); // does not work 

    }

}
```

Comment: `WaitNamedPipe` is a #define and is either `WaitNamedPipeA` or `WaitNamedPipeW` depending if the caller is using ANSII or UNICODE respectively.  Source (see Unicode and ANSI names section): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365800(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? I don't see any relation here.

Comment: @RichardCritten : your comment fix my problem , do you want to convert it to answer so I can award it to you ?

Comment: You most likely shouldn't be using `long` in your interface mapping unless you know for certain the native call is expecting a 64-bit value.  `NativeLong` exists to map onto native `long`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WaitNamedPipe` is a #define and is either `WaitNamedPipeA` or `WaitNamedPipeW` depending if the caller is using ANSII or UNICODE respectively. Source (see Unicode and ANSI names section): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365800(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you use JNA's [`W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/win32/W32APIOptions.html#DEFAULT_OPTIONS) when instantiating your library, the mapping will happen automagically.